# Are racist/xenophobic opinions sufficient to revoke tenure?

Tags: united-states, tenure-track

Think of a tenured (in the US!) professor who asserts something like "Jews are nepotistic" or "Shoot all Muslims and let Allah sort them out" (the latter statement is a real example although better described as xenophobic rather than racist). Assuming that such a professor grades fairly and shows no behaviour in line with those assertions (e.g. attacking Jews or Muslims on the street), are these statements grounds enough for revoking tenure? And does it make a difference if he expresses these opinions

1. in scholarly literature
2. in class
3. on his own social media account
4. in a magazine
5. on the social media account of someone else, perhaps even a /one of his own students.

My understanding is that such opinions are covered by the free speech laws in the US and only in cases where these statements can be reasonably construed as targeted harassment (and happen repeatedly) tenure can be revoked.

I ask because I had an argument with someone that got out of hand because I think that opinions that can be reasonably construed as racist are no grounds for termination.

Comment: How can such an argument get out of hand? It is just an empirical question. Just look up the relevant laws and jurisprudence. I can see such an argument get out of hand if you misunderstood one another, i.e. one thinking the question is *should* such a person loose tenure and the other *can* such a person loose tenure.

Comment: Some relevant case law [here](https://www.aaup.org/get-involved/issue-campaigns/speak-speak-out-protect-faculty-voice/legal-cases-affecting-academic). see for example Sheldon v. Dhillon. Also relevant: [AAUP overview](https://www.aaup.org/academic-freedom-students-and-professors-and-political-discrimination)

Comment: The university being public or private may also be a factor here.

Comment: @ssquidd Thanks, I hope that some answers take these differences into account!

Comment: This question currently seems to be either opinion based or ambiguous.  It might be possible to edit it to not be opinion-based.

Comment: Within the last few days, a tenured professor at an engineering school in New York state was terminated amidst complaints about his social media posts.  We don't know the details of his case, exactly how the institution reached its decision, what the AAUP might have to say about this, or what might happen in a lawsuit for wrongful termination.  The specific details of the case matter a lot, and this Stack Exchange group is no place to discuss this or similar cases.

Answer (score 4):

There are [four common reasons](http://higheredprofessor.com/2017/08/07/can-tenured-faculty-member-fired/) for tenured professors to be fired:

1. **Incompetence**. Used here in the more general sense of the word, it means that if the tenured professor is no longer able to carry out his or her duties - for example if he or she becomes vegetative after an accident - then they can be fired.
2. **Negligence**. If the professor is able to do the work, but does not do it, then it could qualify as negligence. For example if the professor decides to go on vacation during semester, thereby leaving the students without instruction, he/she could be fired.
3. **Immoral conduct**. If the professor sexually harasses a student, commits a (serious) crime like robbery, or violates academic norms (e.g. plagiarism), he/she could be fired.
4. **Financial exigency**. If the university runs out of money for whatever reason, it can fire professors.

Holding unpopular opinions don't come under any of these four reasons. The most one could argue is that it's immoral, but that would be hard to defend since not everyone agrees that racist/xenophobic behavior is wrong. After all it was pretty common to have racist/xenophobic behavior in the past or even today.

**But**: it has happened in the past. Professor Edward Ross of Stanford University was effectively fired by Jane Stanford, one of Stanford's founders, back in 1900. Ross expressed some violently racist opinions of Asians. His firing was controversial, and he was defended by many academics who viewed the dismissal as arising from political reasons and therefore a violation of academic freedom. You can read more about it in articles like [this one](https://stanfordmag.org/contents/watch-your-words-professor). I would venture that if Ross lived today he'd be less likely to be forced out, but it'd be within the realm of possibility, and regardless of whether he's fired or not it would still be controversial.

Comment: I would say, it depends a bit on how those opinions are expressed. If the professor spends all of their classes ranting instead of teaching, that could be seen as neglicence. Even worse, if the students aren't graded objectively but according to prejudices, that would certainly be illegal and immoral. Both are however hard to prove to a degree that will hold up in court.

Answer (score 1):

Opinions of that sort are usually (minimally) tolerated, and are unlikely to affect tenure unless the opinions cross over into discriminatory actions. There are a few exceptions, but there are also quite a few "distinguished" scholars who held quite [abhorrent opinions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robert_Lee_Moore). If you are a renowned scholar in your field, you are safer, of course, than otherwise.

And note that this is a US view and is based not just on general tenure principles but on the first amendment to the Constitution which is also considered here as a factor in such things even when it may not apply in a legal sense. Even private colleges, while not bound by the all of the rules that apply to state and federal governments, are generally required to be accredited (so that students can get grants and loans). They are then bound by the rules of the accrediting agencies, which are, themselves informed by the general principles of the Constitution in the US. Again, there are exceptions but not so many. The exceptions tend to stand out, in fact.

But don't expect to be invited to social events or invited to interact with students if your views (well, their views, actually) imply that you hold prejudices that you are unwilling to overcome.

And the antidote to bad speech is more and better speech.

But yes, harassment is an *action* that can earn you a quick path to the door. So can some more subtle things.

And for tenure decisions of junior faculty, such opinions if expressed are unlikely to win you many votes. But that is pre-tenure.

A friend/colleague of mine was once fired for speaking out against the Vietnam War. The decision was very political and the university was widely condemned throughout academia for the action.

It is also important to note that the fundamental purpose of [tenure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Academic_tenure) is to permit scholars to hold and express [unpopular views](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galileo_Galilei). I'll argue that if you can be fired for speech alone, then you may hold *tenure in name* but you don't hold *tenure in fact*.

Comment: The first amendment to the constitution doesn't apply to the many private institutions of higher learning in the U.S....

Comment: @ff524, not in a legal sense, but it does inform opinion in the US. And some private colleges do explicitly discriminate on religious grounds. But a person wouldn't get hired in the first place if they don't accept the parochial view.

Comment: [Relevant xkcd](https://xkcd.com/1357/)

Comment: @Buffy Thanks. But when does the voicing of an opinion become harassment? Posting on someones facebook wall? Tweeting about it whilst having a massive following?

Comment: Those are, perhaps, judgement calls that could be harassment or not. DOXing someone is clearly harassment. Threats, intimidation, etc. And someone accused of a tenure violation has a process by which it can be handled. So, independent views can come in to play.